# Use MACROS to highlight a cell when any one checkbox is checked (multiple checkboxes, one cell)

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox, highlight

I'm a real newbie with excel (and coding).  I've figure out, using Conditional Formatting, to highlight one cell if the value of another cell changes (based on a checkbox changing).  What I have are multiple cells with checkboxes (cannot be ActiveX checboxes since MAC users need to be able to run it), if any one of those checkboxes are checked, another cell has to be highlighted.
For example, Cells A1, B1, C1, D1, E1 all have check boxes.  If any one of those are checked, cell F1 needs to be highlighted.  I was able to set it up so that if A1 is checked, then cell G1 says "TRUE" then cell F1 highlights.  When I link all the checkboxes to cell G1 and select only B1 - all cells (A1, C1, D1, E1) are checked AND cell F1 is highlighted.  
I need to be able to have one cell highlighted if any one of (or all) A1, B1, C1, D1, and/or E1 is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can have each check box link to its own cell, for example A2, B2, C2, D2, E2. Then use a formula in G1

```
=COUNTIF(A2:E2,TRUE)
```

Use G1 as the input for your conditional format. If no box is checked it will be 0, if any box is checked it will be greater than 0.

[image]

**Edit after comment:** If you use hundreds of check boxes in the spreadsheet grid, then you're not using Excel efficiently. Check boxes are form controls, which means they are good for using in forms. In the grid they are best used sparingly, for exactly the issues that you are encountering.

Consider using cell values instead of check boxes. Format the cells with the Marlett font and type an "a" or a "b" to produce a check mark in the cell. Then you can use a `Countif($A2:$F2,"a")` as the input for your conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  This is essentially what I have right now, but you don't actually need the extra cell (G1). However, there are multiple (like hundreds) of checkboxes and to write something and link extra cells to each checkbox seems unnecessary.  I'm sure there is a Macros or VB script that could accomplish this! I'm just not very good at that.

Comment: For example, I link the checkbox in A1 to the cell G1 (right click checkbox and under form control, cell link: $G$1).  Then in cell F1 I am using this rule under conditional formatting: =G1=TRUE and select the formatting to be highlight yellow.  Only problem is I have do this hundreds of times in a workbook. (about 9 times per row), so I'm sure there is a simple way using VBA/Macros...

Comment: I added a suggestion to my answer.